# How can I use jQuery to dynamically load html into an iFrame?

Tags: jquery, iframe, asyncfileupload

I'm working on an `iframe` file uploader (so my file uploader appears to be ajax). I'm trying to take the form on my page and insert it into an `iframe`. Then I will submit the form inside the `iframe`. However, it isn't working. Here is my code:

jQuery:

```
function submitFile() {
    $(document).ready(function() {
        if ($('[name=files]').val() != "")
        {
            var fileForm = $('#attachFile').html();
            $('#emptyDiv').html('<iframe name="hiddenIframe" id="hiddenIFrame">'+fileForm+'</iframe>');
        }
    });
}
```

HTML:

```
<body>
    <div id="emptyDiv"></div>
    <div id="attachFile">
        <form action="my_file.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="uploadFile">
            <input type="file" name="files" id="files">
            <input id="fileUploadButton" type="submit" name="upload" value="Upload File" onclick="submitFile()">
        </form>
    </div>
</body>
```

This obviously isn't a complete solution, but I notice that after submitting the form I do manage to get the `iframe` inserted into the `<div id="emptyDiv">` element. However, inside the `iframe` is the following code:

```
#document
<html>
    <head></head>
    <body></body>
</html>
```

But what I expect to see inside the `iframe` is the html contents located inside the form `<div id="attachFile">`. What am I missing?

Comment: An iframe has a src attribute, this is how it gets content, not by inserting some html in between the <iframe> tags.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't try to copy the form to a hidden iframe, you submit the form to the hidden iframe. Set the `target` attribute (or property) of the form to the name of the iframe.

```
var fileForm = $('#attachFile form').prop('target', 'hiddenIframe');
$('#emptyDiv').html('<iframe name="hiddenIframe" id="hiddenIFrame"></iframe>');
```

or

```
<form action="my_file.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="uploadFile" target="hiddenIframe">
    <input type="file" name="files" id="files">
    <input id="fileUploadButton" type="submit" name="upload" value="Upload File" onclick="submitFile()">
</form>
```

Comment: That's an interesting way to do it!

Comment: I haven't seen it done that way, though I don't often work with iFrames. Does this with for you Ann? If so, which browser(s) did you test it in? This will help in the future when people find this answer.

Comment: @NickBork this is quite common, pretty much the only way to fake ajax file uploads without plugins. http://jsfiddle.net/mowglisanu/Q7AkY/

Answer (score 1):

Try turning your HTML into a separate page and referencing it with the `src` attribute of the `iframe`.