# File upload fields from html form aren't sent to server

Tags: jquery, html, ajax, spring, httprequest

In my current spring project, some of the forms have fields for the user upload image files to the server. But when I check which parameters are being sent to server using the Network Monitor from Browser (Firefox), I notice the  file upload fields are not sent to server (only the regular fields are listed).

I ever knew only the fields which have the atribute `name` are sent to server, and I make sure this fields have this atributes. the html code for the form is similar to this:

```
    <form id="command" role="form" class="form" action="Categoria/cadastra" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <fieldset>
    <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-heading">
        </div>
        <div class="panel-body">
            <p>
            <label for="nome" class="form-control">nome</label>
            <input id="nome" name="nome" class="form-control" type="text" value=""/>
            </p>
        </div>
    </div>
        <div class="panel panel-default include">
            <div class="panel-heading">
                Selecione um arquivo de imagem para <i>capa da categoria</i>
            </div>
            <div class="panel-body">
                <input type="file" name="file" class="form-control"/>
            </div>
        </div>
    <p>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-lg btn-primary">Cadastrar</button>
    </p>
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

the request is handled by this method in my controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value="cadastra", method=RequestMethod.POST)
@ResponseBody
public String cadastrea(@ModelAttribute("object") E object, BindingResult result, @RequestParam(value="file", required=false) MultipartFile file) {
    if(serv.cadastra(object)) {
        if(serv.upload_picture(object, file))
            return "yes";
        else
            return "data";
    }
    else {
        return "not";
    }
}
```

Right now, I using a jquery script to handle the process of sending the request to server, receive the response and display a message to user telling the result od the processing. This is the script I am using:

```
$(document).on('submit', '.form', function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    var $form = $( this ),  url = $form.attr( "action" );
    var posting = $.post( url, $(this).serialize() );
    posting.done(function( data ) {
        var alert = $("#"+data); 
        alert.css("display", "block");
        alert.fadeOut(2500);
        $(".form").each(function(){
            this.reset();
        });
    });
});
```

I was told fields of type `file` cannot be sent using ajax calls. Is this true? If yes, Is there any other way of do the same without the script (capture the response from server and display an message in the same page instead of redirect to another page)?

Comment: Browsers that support XHR2 can do Ajax file uploads, for other browsers you use an iframe as the forms target.

Comment: @Musa I try submit the form both with firefox and chrome (the last versions), and face the same problem. How I can use iframe for this?

Comment: Hidden iframe example - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16380997/how-can-i-use-jquery-to-dynamically-load-html-into-an-iframe/16381047#16381047 XHR2 example http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22425110/file-not-uploaded-to-the-server-with-ajax/22425210#22425210

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at the [jqueryform](http://malsup.com/jquery/form/) plugin.  I believe they get around this issue by wrapping the uploaded file in a hidden iframe and passing it using the ajaxSubmit function.

Something along the lines of

```
$('#yourForm').ajaxSubmit({
type: 'POST',
url: 'yourUrl'
});
```

ought to do the trick.  In your controller, you would then take a look at `HttpContext.Current.Request.Files` and process the items inside of that collection.